# Guide to migrate Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, opensilver

We are planning to migrate our Silverlight application which having both business and UI logic to new technology. Is there any standard procedures or tools available for silverlight migration.

We want to move to standard technology like html and supported by all windows/mac/Linux browsers. Please give us any suggestions

Answer (score 7):

There is no straight-forward migration path from Silverlight to any technology, despite probably to WPF to a degree, but as you mentioned that you want to run in the browser, probably the best way today is to use [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor), which just got its first official release, and Microsoft is heavily investing in it right now.

On top of that, the French company Userware [created](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/03/09/opensilver.aspx?m=1) the [OpenSilver](https://www.opensilver.net/) platform, which is a Silverlight replacement based on WebAssembly and Blazor, compatible with all major browsers. They even [provide](https://opensilver.net/announcements/introducing-opensilver.aspx) [professional migration services](https://opensilver.net/migrate/upload-xap.aspx) based on this approach.

There is also rich ecosystem already evolved, with a lot of third-party UI components vendors (like [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui), [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/blazor-razor-components/), [Radzen](https://blazor.radzen.com/), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

At Mobilize.Net we have a migration tool that converts the client side XAML and C# to TypeScript using Angular, Kendo UI, HTML, and CSS. It supports C# constructs like generics and interfaces.

You can watch a [live stream from Twitch here](https://mobilize.wistia.com/medias/dosg7opq0)  This is an approach most suitable for very large complex SL web apps that would be too time consuming or expensive to rewrite into a pure native approach.